# Delete a point from your figure after plotting it

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am writing a GUI program. In one part of it I show an image on my axes and then plot a red * on my image then I do some processes on the image and now I want to delete the red *
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you need to use the 'visible' flag. You can access this via the ***children of the current axis object***. See the example code below. You can use the final line of code to set the visibility of the red 'X' on and off . . .

```
close all;

plot ([1 2 3 4], [1 2 1 2])
hold on 
plot(2.5, 1.5, 'xr')

dataH = get(gca, 'Children');
set( dataH(1), 'Linewidth', 10, 'MarkerSize', 30 )

pause
set( dataH(1), 'visible', 'off' )
pause
set( dataH(1), 'visible', 'on' )
pause
set( dataH(1), 'visible', 'off' )
pause
set( dataH(1), 'visible', 'on' )
```